# JS: Replace null value in array with an average of the previous and next value

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have the following array

```
[5,2,null,5,9,4]
```

I need to replace `null` with the average of the previous and next values (2 and 5). Like so:

```
[5,2,3.5,5,9,4]
```

Additionally, if I had an array with consecutive null values:

```
[5,2,null,null,9,4]
```

I would like to be able to replace them with the step values between the 2 and 9. Like so:

```
[5,2,4.33,6.63,9,4]
```

Edit: Guys, totally not a homework assignment. I'm trying to do some stuff with the Chartist-js library.

Here's what I've got that works to replace null with the values before and after.

```
var seriesData = [5,2,null,5,null,4]

seriesData.forEach(function(value, index){
    if ( value === null ) {
        var prev = seriesData[index - 1];
        var next = seriesData[index + 1];
        seriesData[index] = (prev + next) / 2;
    }
});

=> [5, 2, 3.5, 5, 4.5, 4]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment you want us to do for you. How about you give it a try, show us what you tried and we will explain why "YOUR" code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does sound like a Chart problem, so here's a crude logic, you can easily improve the code:

```
function test(){
  var arr = [5,3,2,null,null,9,4, null, null, null, 10, null, 12],
    ind = -1,
    prevIndex,
    nJumps, valJump;

for( var currIndex = 0; currIndex< arr.length; currIndex++ ){
  if( arr[ currIndex] == null ){
    continue;
  }else if( prevIndex === undefined || (nJumps = (currIndex- prevIndex)) === 1 ){
    prevIndex = currIndex;
    continue;
  }

  valJump = (( arr[ currIndex ] - arr[ prevIndex ]) / nJumps);

  ind = (+prevIndex);
  while( ++ind < (+currIndex) )
      arr[ ind ] = (arr[ ind-1 ]) + valJump;

  prevIndex = currIndex;
}

return arr;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This got me sorted. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

This solves your first problem:

```
var arr = [5, 2, null, 5, 9, 4];

var result = arr
  .map(function (x) {
    if (x == null) {
      return (arr[arr.indexOf(x) - 1] + arr[arr.indexOf(x) + 1]) / 2 ;
    }

    return x;
  });

console.log(result); // [5, 2, 3.5, 5, 9, 4]
```

For the second problem I don't quite understand what you mean with the two steps stuff.

Comment: Thanks Dave ... as for the two steps, what I mean is that if there were a linear progression between the two values that have been entered (in this case: 2 and 9), then those 2 null values would be 4.33 and 6.63. So that the line graph creates a straight line between 2 and 9 with all four of those points. Hope that helps, please let me know if still unclear